# How to apply a collection of filters to a Java stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I apply a collection of predicates to a Java stream?

The following code shall illustrate what I have in mind:

```java
final Collection<Predicate<MyObject>> filters = getFilters();
final Stream<MyObject> oStream = getMyObjectStream();
oStream
   .filterAll(filters) // <- this one doesn't exist
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

I'm currently using a function `.filter(m -> applyAllFilters(m, filters))` with a classic loop, but wonder if there is a more "streamy" way?

```java
boolean applyAllFilters(final MyObject m, final Collection<Predicate<MyObject>> filters) {
   Iterator Predicate<MyObject> iter = filters.iterator();
   while(iter.hasNext()) {
      Predicate<MyObject> p = iter.next();
      if (!p.test(m)) {
         return false;
      }
   } 
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `Collection<Predicate>` and join them together using `Predicate.and()` or `Predicate.or()` as appropriate. `getFilters()` should return this `Predicate`, not a collection of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply reduce all the predicates into one single Predicate that is anded with all of them like this:

```
oStream
    .filter(filters.stream().reduce(Predicate::and).orElseThrow())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Alternatively, if you expect the list of filters to be empty in some cases, you could do it this way:

```
oStream
    .filter(filters.stream().reduce(o -> true, Predicate::and))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Does Predicate::and stop when the first `false` gets encountered? I presume so.

Comment: @stwissel Yes, [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#and-java.util.function.Predicate-) say it returns *"a composed predicate that represents the short-circuiting logical AND of this predicate and the other predicate"*.

Comment: Yes. `Predicate::and` is a simple `&&` of the two predicates, so it evaluates lazily. You can actually check the implementation which is: `return (t) -> test(t) && other.test(t);`

Answer (score 2):

You can pre-create a filter that meet all the criteria.

Suppose you have three `Predicate <MyObject> a, b, c`. These can be combined as follows regardless of `oStream`.

```
Predicate<MyObject> allFilter = e -> a.test(e) && b.test(e) && c.test(e);
```

So you can do like this.

```
Predicate<MyObject> filterAll = filters.stream()
    .reduce(Predicate::and).orElse(e -> true);

oStream
   .filter(filterAll)
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Are you sure? The predicates get applied to the members of the oStream which are not available at time of precreation. so `Predicate::and` doesn't get an input. Or do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to apply the filters:

```java
final Collection<Predicate<MyObject>> filters = getFilters();

Stream<MyObject> oStream = getMyObjectStream();
for(Predicate<MyObject> p : filters) {
    oStream = oStream.filter(p);
}
oStream.forEach(System.out::println);
```